# is it appropriate to use a ternary operator here?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that checks the length of some values; if one fails, `var pass` is set to `false`. Another function checks the validity of an email address and sets it to false if it doesn't pass the test. I'm trying to make a custom error message.

Is it better to use a ternary operator like this, or a nested if-statement. Or is there a much simpler way to do it?

```
var mail = true;
var pass = true;
var err = '';

(mail && pass) ? err = 'mail and pass both true' : (!mail && pass) ? err = 'not mail and is pass' : (mail && !pass) ? err = 'is mail and not pass' : err = 'neither pass nor mail';
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/4SfTj/)

Comment: Why not just do it the _readable_ way and use standard if statements?

Comment: I'd go with `if`s, as the ternary is fairly unreadable even for smallish expressions, and multiple nested ternaries quickly descend into madness.

Comment: For future reference, ternary operators are supposed to contain expressions, not statements. It would make more sense to factor out the `err =` and write something like `err = cond ? 'string 1' : (...mess of ternary operators...)`. Though I agree with what everyone is implying here. Use `if`s.

Comment: @TomSmilack Good point.Going for the nested ifs. thanks

Comment: While ifs are certainly clear, if you follow what @TomSmilack you *can* make nested ternaries straightforward to read with some judicious formatting, per my answer... however, that's just an alternative approach and it's not inherently *better* than a series of if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only syntactic issue you might run into is the associativity of the ternary operator. Using brackets to reduce ambiguity helps.

The main problem is that that line is barely readable by humans. Nested ifs are much easier to read, and maintain. Imagine yourself in two months coming back to that line and trying to decipher it.

Answer (score 7):

"Better" is inherently a value judgement, and so it's up to you. Look at the ternary version, and look at the `if/else` version, and decide which is more readable, maintainable, and clear. That's the one you should choose. It doesn't matter to the compiler, which will end up doing something quite efficient regardless.

Comment: And I think I know which one it will be.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Yeah, me to, but I didn't like to lead the witness. :)

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin which one will it be?!

Comment: @thomas long ternary chains are not readable. Just try to write it in both ways, and see in an hour which you can read better.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the clarity of the code i would use if\else...

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice idiom that you can use that looks a little like a lookup table:

```
var mail = true;
var pass = true;
var err = '';

err = ( mail &&  pass)  ?  'mail and pass both true' 
    : (!mail &&  pass)  ?  'not mail and is pass'
    : ( mail && !pass)  ?  'is mail and not pass' 
    :                      'neither pass nor mail';
```

Of course, it's all subjective as to which is better, but this can be a nice way to replace a series of if statements if the only action is assigning to a single variable.

That said, it does combine the visual compactness of the ternary, while addressing the innate illegibility of a one line ternary. On the downside, if later code requires you to do more than select an expression according to your booleans, then you'll need to refactor this to if-else statements anyway...

Answer (score 0):

There are already some good thoughts in the existing answers. Just for the comprehensiveness' sake, here's a declarative solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/Shedal/4SfTj/1/

```
var statusStrings = {
    true: {
        true: 'mail and pass both true',
        false: 'is mail and not pass'
    },
    false: {
        true: 'not mail and is pass',
        false: 'neither pass nor mail'
    }
}

var mail = true;
var pass = true;
var err = statusStrings[mail][pass];

document.write(err);
```

Comment: This is object notation. If you have `var a = { b: 'c' }`, you can either read and write the value of `b` using `a['b']`. It's the same as `a.b`.